# Angular 4 Class vs new ClassName() Difference

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a sample Application which has a model below.

Product Class Contain Stocks and Category Class and Pass the Product Class in component.

In product Component , which one i need to use here for binding in three different grid.

```
 productResposne = new Product();  // which is best 1st 

  productResponse = Product;  // What is the main difference between 1st and 2nd.

   productResposne = Array<Product>[]; //3rd 



 export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{



       productResponse = Product;

    or 
    productResposne = new Product();

    or 

    productResposne = Array<Product>[]
```

Structure;

```
export class Product{

productId:number;
productName:string;
productprice:number;
productcategory:ProductCategory;
productstocks:Stocks;

}

export class ProductCategory{
categoryID:number;
categorytype:string;
categoryPlace:string;

}

export class Stocks{
StockId:number;
StockQty:number;
StocktotalPrice:number;

}


In component:


export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{

productResponse = Product;

or 
productResposne = new Product();

or 

productResposne = Array<Product>[]


ngOnInit(){
this.getProduct();
}
 getProduct(){
 this._productService.getProduct(productId).subscribe(responsess => {

// get the response
 this.responsess = responsess;

bind in category grid
    this.ProductCategory = responsess[0].ProductCategory;

/

/ bind ins stock grid
    this.Stocks = responsess[0].Stocks;
// bind in product grid
    this.Product = responsess[0].Product;

    // These 3 resposes show it in three different grid

    }),(err)=> {this.errorMsg =<any>err};


    }
```

Code is working fine , i need to know the difference between this two:

```
productResposne = new Product();  // which is best 1st 

  productResponse = Product;
```

which is best strategy.

Comment: Sorry, you are asking what's the difference between `Product` and `new Product()`? I don't know what you have, but I asure you that they aren't interchangeable. `Product` is the class constructor, and `new Product()` is an instance of that class.

Comment: First: you specify only type of variable, second: you create instance of class. Third: you have array of type `Product`. And it is not specification of Angular, it is TypeScript basics

Answer (score 4):

As you may (or may not) know, Typescript needs a compiler to work.

Once the code is compiled, it is valid Javascript.

And in Javascript, **there are no classes** per se : functions handle objects creation.

so when you write that

```
productResposne = new Product();
```

You **call a function to create an object**

And when you call that

```
productResponse = Product;
```

You **reference the function with another reference**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simply case of pointers: if you don't use `new`, when referring to the object you change it's value and this will happen if you put your object inside a variable and next you change it's value too.

Of course the best strategy is using `new` because you could refer to the object any times you want, creating a `singleton` (if we could call so) of that object, treating it like an interface